# why is my NVIDIA docker not working? Error response from daemon?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, tensorflow, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to install NVIDIA docker.
I used these lines:

```
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | \
  sudo apt-key add -
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)

curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list

sudo apt-get update
```

and then:

`$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-docker`

Now trying to check if it installed correctly by typing:

`nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi`

This error appears:

> nvidia-docker | 2018/11/06 13:09:24 Error: Got permission denied while
>   trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at
>   unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.38/version: dial unix
>   /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Later I tried:

`sudo nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi`

This error appears:

> Using default tag: latest latest: Pulling from nvidia/cuda
>   473ede7ed136: Pull complete  c46b5fa4d940: Pull complete 
>   93ae3df89c92: Pull complete  6b1eed27cade: Pull complete 
>   d31e9163d0a5: Pull complete  8668af631f88: Pull complete 
>   0d99f8ab6ae2: Pull complete  74440c29d798: Pull complete  Digest:
>   sha256:a6b5fd418d1cd0bc6d8a60c1c4ba33670508487039b828904f8494ec29e6b450
>   Status: Downloaded newer image for nvidia/cuda:latest docker: Error
>   response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"nvidia-smi\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

I install Linux with Ubuntu.
Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors which are quite self explicites.

First of all, it seems your login user is not allowed to connect to docker daemon. 
This is quite a standard issue, you just need to add your user login to docker group, It should solve this issue. You will need to logout/login again for this change to become active.

Second, this is also quite a standard linux issue, your shell has a environment variable called PATH , containing all folders where it will be looking for a command binary, when this command doesn't contain full path to the binary.

For exemple, when you typed curl to download docker-nvidia, your shell find it in `/usr/bin/` folder, because this folder is declared into the PATH variable.

Same applies for containers you download and different users on your local system. You can investigate this specific error message and find this issue on github: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/388

Comment: To add your username do sth like: sudo usermod -aG docker <<user name>>

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference adding this note.

The latest tag is deprecated, and this error is expects:

Look under **Deprecated: "latest" tag** on https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda

Answer (score 0):

Start by setting the GPG and remote repo for the package

`$ curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | \ sudo apt-key add - distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | \ sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list`

Then update the apt lists

`$ sudo apt-get update`

Now you install nvidia-docker (2) and reload the Docker daemon configurations

`$ sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2`

`$ sudo pkill -SIGHUP dockerd`

Nvidia GPUs first require drivers to be installed. Here is how you make sure they are installed

`$ sudo apt-get remove nvidia -384 ; sudo apt-get install nvidia-384`

Now, the only thing left to do is test your environment and to make sure everything is installed correctly. Just simply launch the nvidia-smi (system management interface) application.

`$ docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda:9.0-base nvidia-smi`

The output will be similar to this:

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| NVIDIA-SMI 390.77                 Driver Version: 390.77                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |

|===============================+======================+======================|

|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0    83W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |     98%

Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

Reference: https://cnvrg.io/how-to-setup-docker-and-nvidia-docker-2-0-on-ubuntu-18-04/